# Nested helpers in Ember handlebars

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a model in my Ember app that has a long text field; this field contains a text formatted with HTML so in Ember template I use the triple brackets to display it:

```
{{{text}}}
```

But now I would like to insert in this text a handlebars helper (in particular a {{link-to}} that opens another page of my app);
Anybody knows how to store in the db a text with handlebars helper inside and render it correctly?

Comment: storing handlebars helpers as part of text sounds like a really bad idea. What if you want to use a different framework tomorrow? Also, conceptually, handlebars helpers and the rendering logic should all be on the client and only on the client.

Comment: Ok got it; but I need to insert a link inside the text (and can't be a simple <a> tag, I need the {{link-to}}; so which one is the best practice to achieve this? Can I use a placeholder in the text and then somehow replace it on the client with the proper {{link-to}} helper?